# Error invoking Method 'saveReceipt': Method 'saveReceipt' not found [404] meteor error

Tags: reactjs, meteor

i am using rubix theme from http://rubix.sketchpixy.com/ in meteor.

i have written a methods on serverside

```
Meteor.methods({
    'saveReceipt':function(){
          GLCodes.insert({
                glcode:'glc',
                customerid:'cid',
                narration:'narration',
                amount:'amt'
          });
    }
});
```

but when i call this method it gives error
Error invoking Method 'saveReceipt': Method 'saveReceipt' not found [404] meteor error

Comment: Are you invoking the call from the client?

Comment: write the code in any common.js or outside the server and client code. I believe you are calling the method from client and its not visible as your method is in server side only.

Comment: It is most likely that you did not import the file that defines this method on your server.